# UNIX: CPU registers when a thread/process is swapped out

Tags: multithreading, stack, multiprocessing, cpu-registers

This may be very trivial, but I couldn't find a clear answer on the web.

My understanding is that when the execution of a thread or a process is swapped with another process or thread, the data in CPU registers needs to be saved. But, my confusion is where this data is saved. Is it copied to stack memory, or it is stored in Process Control Block/Thread Control Block . Any comments will be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Yes on context switches the process or thread state is stored in a PCB or tcb. The PCB and tcb are in memory

Comment: Thanks Rafael, this will help.